# Editing same document-node multiple times in XQuery in memory

Tags: xml, xpath, functional-programming, xquery, saxon

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
    <root>
    <content>
        <z>valZ</z>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>valC</c>
            </b>
            <b>
                <c>valC</c>
            </b>
        </a>
        <a>
            <d>valD</d>
        </a>
    </content>
</root>
```

Number of nodes "a" can be from 1 to some undefined number no higher than 30
Number of "b" , "c" and "d" nodes can be from 0 to some undefined number no higher than 20 too

What I need to do in XQuery is to take value of node "z" and copy it to every existing node "b" so the structure every time will look like this:

```
   <root>
    <content>
        <z>valZ</z>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>valC</c>
                <z>valZ</z>
            </b>
            <b>
                <c>valC</c>
                <z>valZ</z>
            </b>
        </a>
        <a>
            <d>valD</d>
            <b>             <!-- <b> was not present here before -->
                <z>valZ</z>
            </b>
        </a>
    </content>
</root>
```

If there is even one block "b", I don't need to create another one just put "z" inside of it (or inside of multiple "b" if more than 1 is present) otherwise in each "a" I need to create a new one.

Seems easy? In any other language than XQuery I would agree - you simply have to take the document, copy value of "z" , iterate over whole document looking for every "a",
check if these found "a" have "b", if not create "b" and within "b" create new "z" with copied value.

But I struggle with iterating over same document and updating it with inmemupdate.xq library. Here is snippet of the code I use for it:

```
    declare function changeSourceForFieldZ($rootDoc as document-node()) as document-node()?  {
    let $value := getValueOfFieldZ($rootDoc)
    return populateBLevelIfValueExists($rootDoc, $value)
    };

    declare %private function getValueOfFieldZ($rootDoc as document-node()) as text()? {
    $rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:z/text()
    };

    declare %private function populateBLevelIfValueExists($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text()?) as document-node()? {
    if(fn:exists($value)) then
        addField($enrichment, $value)
    else
        $rootDoc
    };


    declare %private function addField($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text()) as document-node()? {
    if (hasBLevel($rootDoc)) then
        insertNodeInBLevel($rootDoc, $value)
    else if (hasALevel($rootDoc)) then
        insertNodeInALevel($rootDoc, $value)
    else ()
    };

    declare %private function hasBLevel($rootDoc as document-node()) as xs:boolean {
    fn:exists($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a/*:b)
    };


    declare %private function hasALevel($rootDoc as document-node()) as xs:boolean {
    fn:exists($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a)
    };

    declare %private function createTagWithZField($value as text()) {
    <z>{$value}</z>
    };

    declare %private function createWholeBtagBlock($value as text()) {
    (
        <b>
            <z>{$value}</z>
        </b>
    )
    };
```

The problem is inserting method obviously. As mentioned earlier, I use mem library, more precisely one function:

```
   declare function mem:node-insert-child(
    $parentNode as element(),
    $newNode as node()*
    ) as node()
```

And if I write insertNodeInBLevel and insertNodeInALevel like that:

```
    declare %private function insertNodeInBLevel($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text()) {
    mem:node-insert-child($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a/*:b, createTagWithZField($value))
    };

    declare %private function insertNodeInALevel($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text()) {
    mem:node-insert-child($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a, createWholeBtagBlock($value))
    };
```

it returns me multiple copies of rootDoc document with values added to different places instead of one document with nodes added in all places.

I tried many solutons, including recursion and looping:

```
   declare %private function insertNodeInBLevel($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text()) {
    if(fn:exists($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a/*:b)) then
        let $nodes := $rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a/*:b
        for $node at $index in $nodes
            let $rootDoc := exampleInsertWithIndex($rootDoc, $value, $index)

        return $rootDoc 
    };

    declare %private function exampleInsertWithIndex($rootDoc as document-node(), $value as text(), $index) {
    mem:node-insert-child($rootDoc/*:root/*:content/*:a/*:b[$index], createTagWithZField($value))
    };
```

But, well, values are immutable so can't save to the same rootDoc for second time and so on... Any idea how to solve this problem, so I will edit multiple nodes of same document and return only this one, not its copies? I am developer of object-oriented languages, functional ones are quite new for me and they follow different paradigm, as such maybe my way of thinking about solution is flawed...

Comment: As you have tagged the question as Saxon, I wonder whether you could use XSLT instead of XQuery? As for the problem, can a single `a` element have `b` and `d` children? What happens in that case, the `d` always remain(s) unchanged?

Comment: With XSLT you can nicely separate the task in templates, see http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3t for an example. But I am sure someone will help you with XQuery too.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.  You are right, XSLT could solve the issue. However it would be best if I could solve it with xQuery, but I am timeboxed with that issue so in worst case scenario I will fallback to XSLT. Regarding your question from comment above, "d" has to remain unchanged at any times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to use XQuery Update (I think this requires the commercial variants of Saxon, but there are also other implementations with support for XQuery Update), simply use a transformation and insert the `<z/>` node into each `<b/>` node:

```
let $z := //z
return
  copy $result := /root
  modify
    for $node in $result//b
    return insert node $z into $node
  return $result
```

If not, recursively walking the tree and reconstructing it while modifying it as needed is a common pattern in XQuery:

```
declare function local:insert-z($subtree as element(), $z as element()) as element() {
   element {node-name($subtree)}
      {$subtree/@*,
          for $node in $subtree/node()
              return
               if ($node instance of element())
                 then
                   (
                     local:insert-z($node, $z),
                     if ($subtree/self::b)
                     then $z
                     else ()
                   )
                 else $node
      }
};

local:insert-z(/root, //z)
```

There is a list of examples how to use this pattern for different use cases in the [XQuery wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Filtering_Nodes).

Comment: Thank you, I will give a try to both proposed solutions!

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with a [typeswitch](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-typeswitch) and some custom logic for those elements

```
declare function local:transform($nodes as node()*) as item()* {
    for $node in $nodes
    return 
        typeswitch($node)
            case text() return $node
            case comment() return $node
            case processing-instruction() return $node
            case attribute() return $node
            case element(a) return local:transform-a($node)
            case element(b) return local:transform-b($node)
            default return local:identity($node)
};

declare function local:transform-a($a as element(a)) as element(a) {
    element a {
        local:transform($a/(@* | node())), 
        if(not(exists($a/b))) then
            element b { root($a[1])/content/z }
        else ()
    }
};

declare function local:transform-b($b as element(b)) as element(b) {
    element b {
        local:transform($b/(@* | node())), 
        if(not(exists($b/z))) then 
          root($b[1])/content/z
        else ()
    }
};

declare function local:identity($node as element()*) as item()* {
    element {name($node)} {($node/@*, local:transform($node/node()))}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This kind of thing is so much easier in XSLT!

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="a[not(b)]">
  <a>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <b><xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::z"/></b>
  </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::z"/>
  </b>
</xsl:template>
```